# Wordpress File edit in dreamhost

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, dreamhost

I used the one click install in dreamhost for my Wordpress sit that I'm building on my sub-domain. When I look for the WP php files in my FTP I can't find them in the directory. Idk where dreamhost places the files?  It's my first time not using local host for developing.

Thx

Comment: This is something you probably want to ask Dreamhost :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template files are in `/wp-content/[yourthemename]/`. There could be any number of .php files in there depending on your theme, the only one that is required is `index.php`.

Under `Appearance > Themes` in your admin panel it should tell you what theme you are using and where the theme directory is.

Comment: Unfortunately in dreamhost when u do "one click" installs the WP php files don't appear in the dub directory

Comment: That is 100% incorrect. I use Dreamhost all the time and WP needs the files to function properly. Use FTP to connect to your server. The files will all be there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for the delayed response.